# How to delete all documents in a Vespa index?

Tags: vespa

What is a clean way to delete all documents in a Vespa index and leave everything else as it is?

Please share API or Vespa CLI option, if it exists.

I want to empty the index, all docs at once.

I found this command: `$ vespa document -v remove id:news:news::1` but this is for deleting individual docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find five ways to do it at [this documentation page](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/operations/batch-delete.html).

I recommend the fourth:

```
curl -X DELETE \
  "$ENDPOINT/document/v1/my_namespace/my_doctype/docid?selection=true&cluster=my_cluster"
```